# permission denied while trying to open a file with python

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, neural-network, command-prompt

I wanted to test tensorflow [model](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow) of [DCGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06434) (a kind of Artificial Neural Network).

First, I downloaded the `mnist` dataset and extracted all of them and I put the extracted files in the `data` folder. So the data directory is like this:

```
{data}->{mnist}->{t10k-images-idx3-ubyte(folder), t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte(folder), train-images-idx3-ubyte(folder), train-labels-idx1-ubyte(folder)}
```

and inside these folders, there are the related `mnist` binary file.

So after that, I wanted to test the model with command:

```
python main.py --dataset mnist --input_height=28 --output_height=28
```

However, I am receiving this error:

> {'batch_size':
>
> 64, 'beta1': 0.5, 'checkpoint_dir': 'checkpoint', 'crop': False,
>   'dataset': 'mnist', 'epoch': 25, 'input_fname_pattern': '*.jpg',
>   'input_height': 28, 'input_width': None, 'learning_rate': 0.0002,
>   'output_height': 28, 'output_width': None, 'sample_dir': 'samples',
>   'train': False, 'train_size': inf, 'visualize': False} 2017-05-19
>   06:39:26.142508: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these
>   are available on your m achine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-05-19 06:39:26.142773: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-05-19 06:39:26.142990: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-05-19 06:39:26.143212: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but
>   these are available on you r machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-05-19 06:39:26.143558: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but
>   these are available on you r machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-05-19 06:39:26.143833: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these
>   are available on your m achine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-05-19 06:39:26.144102: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-05-19 06:39:26.144438: W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The
>   TensorFlow li brary wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these
>   are available on your m achine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-05-19 06:39:26.219026: I
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:887]
>   Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce 820M major: 2 minor: 1
>   memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.25 pciBusID 0000:03:00.0 Total memory: 2.00GiB
>   Free memory: 1.94GiB 2017-05-19 06:39:26.219532: I
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:908]
>   DMA: 0 2017-05-19 06:39:26.219721: I
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:918] 0:
>   Y 2017-05-19 06:39:26.219874: I
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gp
>   u\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:950]
>   Ignoring visi ble gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce 820M, pci bus
>   id: 0000:03:00.0) with Cu da compute capability 2.1. The minimum
>   required Cuda capability is 3.0. Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 97, in  tf.app.run() File
>   "C:\Users\vafaee\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow35\lib\site-packages\tensorflo
>   w\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
>   _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "main.py", line 61, in main sample_dir=FLAGS.sample_dir) File
>   "C:\Users\vafaee\Documents\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\DCGAN-tensorflow-maste
>   r\model.py", line 74, in init self.data_X, self.data_y =
>   self.load_mnist() File
>   "C:\Users\vafaee\Documents\DCGAN-tensorflow-master\DCGAN-tensorflow-maste
>   r\model.py", line 467, in load_mnist fd =
>   open(os.path.join(data_dir,'train-images-idx3-ubyte'))
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   './data\mnist\train-images-idx3
>   -ubyte'

I am running the command prompt as administrator but it didn't work.

I have also checked the permission with right clicking on the folder/file and going to the "security" tab and checking permission. Every thing seemed fine.

So far, I was not able to solve it by looking for previous questions.

I am using Windows 8 and I am running the code via a coda environment.

I appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: I'd say that you've got an unescaped backslash issue: ` './data\mnist\train-images-idx3 -ubyte'` at least for the tabulation char.

Comment: sotrrry  I did not understand. can you please explain more? @jea

Comment: sorry I did not understand very well. can you please explai n more? @jean-FrancoisFabre

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem with the following solution:

Actually, this code is written to be used in Linux. However, my platform was Windows. In the "model.py" script and in the load_mnist() function, the code for loading data was `data_dir = os.path.join("./data", self.dataset_name)`

However, in Windows, you can not access to the current directory by "./" code. So I changed this line to the following lines:

```
current_dir = os.getcwd()
data1_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'data')
data2_dir = os.path.join(data1_dir, 'mnist')
data_dir = os.path.join(data2_dir, 'train-images-idx3-ubyte')
```

After that, in the source code there was this line:

fd = open(os.path.join(data_dir,'train-images-idx3-ubyte'))

which was trying to open the directory. So I changed it to this one:
`fd = open(os.path.join(data_dir,'train-images.idx3-ubyte'), "r+")

Now it worked for me. The thing is that this code was guaranteed to work, except from the windows part, it was trying to open the directory note the file itself. 
I hope this can help other people as well.
`